# Changes in conductivity of CuSO4 solution after NH3 solution is added

Tags: experimental-chemistry, coordination-compounds, conductivity

In my high school chemistry class we are writing a lab. Originally, I wanted to measure the rate of a ligand exchange reaction at different temperatures by measuring changes in conductivity. After some discussion, I came to the conclusion that there would be no change in conductivity and therefore I would not be able to use this method. Nonetheless, I decided to do the test the method; the results can be seen below:

[image]

This was quite a surprising result and so I decided to look at the reaction that occurs more closely. The full reaction is as follows:

Initially the solution consists of $\ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^{2+}_{(aq)}}$.

Once ammonia is added, the following reactions occur:

$$\ce{NH3_{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)} <=> OH- _{(aq)} + NH4+_{(aq)}}$$

$$\ce{Cu^{2+}_{(aq)}+ 2OH- _{(aq)} <=> Cu(OH)2 _{(s)}}$$

A continued addition of ammonia results in:

$$\ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^{2+}_{(aq)} + 4NH3 _{(aq)} <=> [Cu(NH3)4(H2O)2]^{2+} + 4H2O_{(l)}}$$

Looking at the reactions above which I obtained from [here](https://chemdemos.uoregon.edu/demos/Copper-Ammonia-Complex), I would assume that the conductivity increases due to the dissociation of water in the presence of ammonia to form ammonium and hydroxide ions. Is this assumption valid? Also, my experiment would like to use conductivity to measure how long it takes for the ligand exchange reaction to occur between the water ligands and ammonia ligands of copper. Would this be feasible, or would I only be measuring the rate at which ammonium and hydroxide is formed?

Note:
- The graph was obtained by using a conductivity sensor
- 25 ml of 35% ammonia solution was added to 25 ml of 0.5 mol $\ce{CuSO4}$ solution in this reaction.

Comment: I took a liberty of numbering your reactions so that they could be referred to. Also, we decided against using MathJax in titles. Now to the point. Did you add the NH3 solution gradually or at once?

Comment: Thank you for informing me, I was not aware of this. The NH3 was added all at once, i.e. I poured it in using a beaker as fast as possible.

Comment: Equation 3 is wrong. Please correct.

Comment: Well, now it is clear. See, the dissociation of water is pretty much instantaneous; it does not take 6 seconds, nor does it take 1. Heterophase reactions, on the other hand, are much slower. As for your reaction (3), it doesn't happen exactly as written, because after the reaction (2) is complete, you don't really have any $\ce{Cu(H2O)6^2+}$ around.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That makes sense, but what would cause the increase in conductivity over 6 seconds?

Comment: As solid Cu(OH)2 turns into the soluble ammonia complex, we're getting more ions in the solution.